# comparing three variables on if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with get pass on the if statement. I have a problem with if statement as I am trying to get pass when I am trying to compare on the values using three variables.

```
start_time = '22:35'
current_time = '23:48'
stop_time = '00:00'

if current_time == start_time:
   print "the program has started"


elif start_time != current_time < stop_time:
    print "program is half way"


elif current_time > stop_time:
    print "program has finished"
```

I can get pass on each if statement with no problem, but my problem is when I have the variable `start_time` with the value `22:35` which it is not equal to `current_time` value `23:48`. So how I can compare with the values between the `start_time` and `current_time` as I want to compare to see if it is less than the value `00:00` from the variable `stop_time`?

I want to check if the value from the variable `stop_time` which is less than the `current_time` and `start_time`.

Just imagine you are watching the tv program which it start at `22:35` in your current time. You are watching which it is less than before the program finish at `00:00`, so you check the time again later before the finish time `00:00`, it say it is still half way through. Then you check it later at your current time which it is after than `00:00` so it say the program has finished.

Well on my code, I will always get pass on the `elif current_time > stop_time:` as i always keep getting the `print "program has finished"` which I should have `print "program is half way"` instead.

How can you compare three values between the variables `start_time` and `current_time` to see if it is less than and check to see if it is less the value `00:00` from the variable `stop_time`?

**EDIT: Here is what I use them as a string when i am getting the hours and minutes from the date format especially year, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds**

```
start_date = str(stop_date[0]) #get start_date date format from database
stop_date = str(stop_date[1]) #get start_date date format from database
get_current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M') 
get_start_time = time.strptime(start_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
start_time = time.strftime('%H:%M', get_start_time)
get_stop_time = time.strptime(stop_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
stop_time = time.strftime('%H:%M', get_stop_time)
current_time = str(get_current_time)
```

Comment: Shouldn't all these time values be actual datetime objects or time.time() values?

Comment: If the times are HH:MM only and you are crossing the day boundary, then you can never compare even 2 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two comparisons and the `and` logical we could create something like this:

```
if current_time > start_time and current_time < stop_time:
    #do work
```

But that actual problem is dealing with [date and time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

```
   current_time = datetime.now() #lets say this is 2016, 2, 12, 17:30
   start_time = datetime.datetime(2016,2,12,16,30) # or datetime.strptime(start_time)
   end_time = datetime.datetime(2016,2,13,0,0)
if current_time == start_time:
    print "the program has started"


elif current_time > start_time and current_time < stop_time:
    print "Program is still running"


elif current_time > stop_time:
    print "program has finished"
```

Comment: I think his problem is that 00:00 is less than every other time.

Comment: thank you, but it did not work very well. I can't get pass on the statement as this one works very well `elif start_time != current_time < stop_time:` but it won't work well if the time is `00:00` or later than for the `stop_time`.

Comment: @spicavigo Oh! Thats an entirely different question than using three variables on an if statement

Comment: No, this is the question that I am asking for on an if statement.

Comment: You will want to use `datetime` objects to make it easier, otherwise you will need additional variables(day,month,year) that would essentially do what the module already does well

Comment: well the type i am using `start_time` is a string, `stop_time` is a string and `current_time` is a string so why should i change it to datetime object?

Comment: coverting a string to a datetime object is fairly [trivial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) and you get [comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.tzinfo) for quite cheap.

Comment: @MichalFrystacky how I can convert a string to a datetime?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103347/discussion-between-michal-frystacky-and-daniel-ezekiel).